# How to fetch all users from Azure Active Directory Group using C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We have an application developed in ASP.NET MVC. We also have Acitve Directory configured in Azure and it has some Groups into it.
Requirement is, we need to fetch all users from Azure Active Directory's Group and add a new user into it.

We are using code below and it is asking extra authentication I guess. we want to provide all authentication in code it self without giving popup wondow to authenticate. Can you please help with this

```
   // Build a client application.
            IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                        .Create("clientID")
                        .WithTenantId("tenantId")
                        .Build();
            // Create an authentication provider by passing in a client application and graph scopes.
            DeviceCodeProvider authProvider = new DeviceCodeProvider(publicClientApplication, new[] { "User.Read" });
            // Create a new instance of GraphServiceClient with the authentication provider.
            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

            var members = await graphClient.Groups["groupId"].Members
                .Request()
                .GetAsync();
```

Above code shows a message as 
*"To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code G9277ULC9 to authenticate."*

How can we provide all authentication information in code itself to avoid this step?

**Updated**
API permissions are as below -

[image]
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is not a question. This is business requirement. You should research, try to do something then if you have any particular code problem, you can ask. But where is the code? I don't see any.

Comment: @JohnB, I understand this may not be right forum. But not sure from where to start hence posted here to get few references.

Comment: @JohnB code is available now, can you please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Microsoft Graph SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdks-overview) to do that.

[List members of a group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example):

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var members = await graphClient.Groups["{id}"].Members
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

[Add member to a group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example):

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var directoryObject = new DirectoryObject
{
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        {"@odata.id","https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{id}"}
    }
};

await graphClient.Groups["{id}"].Members.References
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(directoryObject);
```

**Update**:

If you want a non-interactive way, you need to use the client credential flow, i.e. create the `authProvider` instance as [Client credentials provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#client-credentials-provider).

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithTenantId(tenantID)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .Build();

ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reference Joy. Will try out and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I just edited the question with code sample, Can you please help with this?

Comment: @Oxygen You need to use `Client credentials provider` instead of the `Device code provider`, see my update. Follow this link to create the `clientSecret`, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#create-a-new-application-secret

Comment: @Oxygen Does it work now? Also don't forget to [grant the `application permission` for your AAD App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent#grant-admin-consent-when-registering-an-app-in-the-azure-portal), check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#permissions) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#permissions).

Comment: Trying now. Sure, will confirm the permission. I think I am confused about where can I find client id.

Comment: @Oxygen You can find the client id [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#get-values-for-signing-in), it was also named application id.

Comment: Excellent Joy. All set up now, permissions too.But getting error as "Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
"

Comment: @Oxygen Did you click the `Grant admin consent` button in the API permissions page?

Comment: yes Joy. Did that, same mentioned in your shared link.

Comment: @Oxygen Could you provide a screenshot of your api permissions in your question?

Comment: @Oxygen Try to add the `Group.ReadWrite.All` permission, then click the `Grant admin consent` again.

Comment: You are Genious @Joy.. Saved me Buddy.. It is working. Let me try adding new user now

Comment: one more q pls - I want to add a new user with email address as "abc.hotmail.com", where can I add this address in AdditionalData mentioned in your answer's line -   {"@odata.id","https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{id}"}

Comment: @Oxygen You need to find the object id of the user, navigate to AAD in the portal ->  `Users` -> find the user `abc.hotmail.com`, click and get `Object ID`, then this line should be `"@odata.id","https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{Object ID}"`. If this account is not in your aad tenant, you need to invite it first by `New guest user`, then login the `abc.hotmail.com` mailbox, accept the invitation.

Comment: Okay. Got you, thanks for clarifying. How can we send invitation using Graph SDK? Cos that's what we want to achieve.

Comment: @Oxygen Use this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example, grant the `User.ReadWrite.All` permission.

Comment: it worked but I don't see any email in my mailbox yet yo accept the invitation. By any way we can send invitation for particular group? It seem we are inviting to add in Tenant right?

Comment: @Oxygen No, you can just invite it to your tenant first, then add it to your group, the invitation should work. And I think it is not related to your original question, actually I have answered your original question `fetch all users from Azure Active Directory's Group and add a new user into it`. If you have more questions about the invitation, you may need to ask it in a new post. Stackoverflow avoid asking several questions in the same post.

Comment: thank you for your time buddy. Really appreciate. Accepted your answer :)

Comment: This is regarding adding user in group. I got newly created user's id and using it in Additional Data as {"@odata.id","https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{my users object id}"} but it is throwing error as : ID is required to add a reference. Any direction please?

Comment: @Oxygen You miss the / after directoryObjects ？

Comment: It was there, sorry it got removed while writing {my user's object id}. I got it working using -    User userToAdd = await graphClient.Users["userobjectid"].Request().GetAsync();
            await graphClient.Groups[groupId].Members.References.Request().AddAsync(userToAdd);

Comment: Could you answer this? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58222315/how-to-get-users-information-from-active-directory-by-email-address-using-micro

Comment: @Oxygen Will have a look tomorrow, now i need to go to bed.:-)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200362/discussion-on-answer-by-joy-wang-how-to-fetch-all-users-from-azure-active-direct).