# How to get user's information from Active Directory by email address using Microsoft Graph sdk

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-sdks

We would like to retrieve user's information from Azure Active directory using Microsoft Graph SDK.

Given a valid email address, but I get an error

> Resource 'myemailaddress@live.com' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.

Code is below. Can you please guide?

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId).WithTenantId(tenantID).WithClientSecret(clientSecret).Build();
ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
var user = await graphClient.Users["myemailaddress@live.com"].Request().GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue. The account `myemailaddress@live.com` is a `Guest` in your tenant, navigate to the AAD in the portal -> find the account -> click it and fetch the `Object ID`, then use the `Object ID` in the code, it will work.

```
var user = await graphClient.Users["<Object ID>"].Request().GetAsync();
```

Or you can use `filter` to get the user, in your case, the format of the `UserPrincipalName` for the guest user will be like `myemailaddress_live.com#EXT#@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com`, when using the filter, we need URL encode it, then it will be `myemailaddress_live.com%23EXT%23%40tenantname.onmicrosoft.com`, try the code as below, it works on my side.

```
var user = await graphClient.Users.Request().Filter("UserPrincipalName eq 'myemailaddress_live.com%23EXT%23%40tenantname.onmicrosoft.com'").GetAsync();
```

**Update**:

If you want to get the user via `UserPrincipalName`, you can also use the url encoded one as below.

```
var user = await graphClient.Users["myemailaddress_live.com%23EXT%23%40tenantname.onmicrosoft.com"].Request().GetAsync();
```

Comment: I am not getting user's info. CurrentPage property is zero.

Comment: It says - Resource 'userprinciplename' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present

Comment: Yes. I have replaced it. How ever I am getting user info if I pass the object id like this -  await graphClient.Users["8728a2d3-0d33-4c59-8c46-948a0b2db568"].Request().GetAsync(); but its not coming when I am passing userprinciple name as above

Comment: Let me try. How are you encoding the string in C#?

Comment: @Oxygen No, I just replace the `#` with `%23` manually like above for a test.

Comment: Okay, you are great Joy. Made my morning. thank you so much again. It worked.