# Is there any API to find all users under a particular tenant id from azure ad?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, botframework, microsoft-teams

> How can I fetch all users from my azure active directory ? I need some API for it.

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58212958/how-to-fetch-all-users-from-azure-active-directory-group-using-c-sharp

Comment: Can I know how the progress of this ticket? Appreciate for considering to accept one of below answer if one if them help you solve the puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Graph API list users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below api:

```
Get https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{org name}/_apis/graph/users?subjectTypes=aad&api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

**Note**: Specify the `subjectTypes` as `aad`.

Then it will fetch all users which are members of organization, also located in the **AAD tenant** that connected with the azure devops organization.

This is the sample response of mine:

[image]